# How do I change the channel on a Yongnuo YN685C flash?

Tags: canon, hotshoe-flash, yongnuo, wireless-flash

I have the Yongnuo YN685C for Canon cameras. I am using the YN622C-TX and also the YN622C.

How do I change the channel on the YN685C?

Comment: Did you look at the manual?

Comment: Just to double-check, you're not using the YN-685C *on* a YN-622C transceiver, are you? The YN-685 has a built-in YN622 radio receiver.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual](https://fccid.io/2ACYPYN685/User-Manual/User-Manual-2943363.pdf) page 21 you should press `CH` button, then rotate `Select Dial` to set the desired channel then press `OK` to confirm